# Best way to encode a tag column for clustering

Tags: nlp, clustering, word-embeddings, encoding, categorical-encoding

I have a dataset which tells me a tech support case used a particular tech document.
Every case has been tagged with which product it pertains to.
Similarly tech documents are tagged with certain key words. Now these tags are not a one-to-one match.
My case can have `{"vpn","rpx series","ipv6 protocol"}` and the tech doc linked to it might have `{"routers","rpx2090","rpx series"}`
So in this case "rpx series" is present in both, hence its highly likely that the doc linked to the case is the correct one.

How can we encode these tag sets to show that there is a definite overlap?
I am looking to preserve more of the syntactic info than the semantic one since these are words.

My goal is to use the encoding for clustering and similarity techniques.
This will be one of the many features used for my exercise.